# Magento 2 : Schedule promo codes

Tags: magento2, promotions, schedule

In Magento 2 how to add automatic schedules to Promo Codes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When creating `Price cart rules` there is `start` and `end` dates selectable (see [this dev doc page](https://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/marketing/price-rules-cart.html)).  These schedule the "promo codes".